# Restrict certain pages for only some user group in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

Here when one type of user is logged in he can access any other user's page by simply changing the URL. How can I restrict certain pages to only certain users along with @login_required

views.py

```
def login_user(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        u = User.objects.get(username=username)
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            if user.groups.filter(name='hod').exists():
                return redirect('/hod')
            elif user.groups.filter(name='principal').exists():
                return redirect('/principal')
            elif user.groups.filter(name='Rep').exists():
                return redirect('/rep')
            elif user.groups.filter(name='Ajithzen').exists():
                return redirect('/ajithsen')
            elif user.groups.filter(name='graphics').exists():
                return redirect('/ashok')
            elif user.groups.filter(name='Event_incharge').exists():
                return redirect('/incharge')
            elif user.groups.filter(name='Event_coord').exists():
                return redirect('/chair')
            elif user.groups.filter(name='IEEE').exists():
                return redirect('/ieee')
            else:       
                return render(request, 'retest/login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid login'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'retest/login.html', {'error_message': 'Your account has been disabled'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'retest/login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid login'})
return render(request, 'retest/login.html')
@login_required
def rep(request):
    u = request.user
    all_requests= Retest.objects.all() 
    return render(request, 'retest/home.html', {'u':u, 'all_requests' : all_requests })
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^$', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
url(r'^rep$', views.rep, name='rep'),
```

If a user of group rep is logged in he can access the page of others by changing /rep to some other

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write your own [decorator](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/11/29/improve-your-python-decorators-explained/) that checks weather the current user is allowed to see the page they are trying to access. This could be done by using sessions. When a user logs in, they get authenticated and given a session variable that corresponds to their rights.